# Could not find generator theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Trying to use the Spree.

```
rails g spree:install
rails g theme my_theme
```

Which returns :

```
Can not find generator theme
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a theme generator installed/setup. If you just run `rails g` you should see a list of all available generators. What does that list say?

Comment: spree:dummy
  spree:install
  spree:sandbox
  spree:site` . I'm just going to build one by hand. There docs are completely outdated. Their edge docs which were relevant to a build a year ago, were tucked away. But after reading them, they also seem outdated. I'm just going to trust my instincts here and work with what I got. Also, hysterical note they make about making sure you set up your app a certain way so that it's easy to upgrade. I followed all the rules. They threw everything out. You can't actually upgrade an old app that was built proper.

Comment: Ok, so if anything the generator would be called `spree:theme` but no such generator exists, so I'm not sure why you were expecting it to be there. Either way, this railscast episode on Spree might be of some help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/298-getting-started-with-spree?view=asciicast

Comment: Thanks normalocity. I very much appreciate the help.